# JavaScript - Regex - How can I replace every char from A to Z except X?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How can I replace every letter in this string without "X" with example "-":

"XASDXDAX".replace(/([A-Z^X])/,"-") should return: "X---X--X"

Something must be wrong in the regex or what else, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, you just need to add the `g` modifier (for "global"), and you can't express both a class and a negated class simultaneously (the `^` is only special in `[]` if it's the first character), so just list the ranges. Also, you don't need the capture group (the `()`):

```
result = "XASDXDAX".replace(/[A-WY-Z]/g,"-");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"XASDXDAX".replace(/([A-WYZ])/g,"-")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple regex you are searching for. Just try this

```
 var str="XASDXDAX".replace(/[^X]/g,"-");
```

Comment: You're assuming no characters out of the range `A-Z` in the string. That's true of the *sample* string, but... That said, the OP did say *"...in **this** string..."*, so +1 for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a negated class with the global modifier `g` to replace each non-X character :

```
"XASDXDAX".replace(/([^X])/g,"-")
```